# How to Show a property like dock property in Designer with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, properties, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

I have a property that defines a direction(like N,S or NE,SW). I wanna make it editable with visual studio's designer. like what we have for `Dock` and `TextAlign` Properties. I have no idea about what to search for, so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wish to implement an Extender Provider.

Please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx